# show random images Image.asset() flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to show random images in image.asset() this is what I have tried

```
     static var listImagesnotFound = [
    "assets/cactusno.jpg",
    "assets/colorednot.jpg",
    "assets/juno.jpg",
    "assets/notfound.png",
    "assets/robno.png",
    "assets/spano.jpg"
  ];
  static var _random = Random();
  var imageToShow =
      listImagesnotFound[_random.nextInt(listImagesnotFound.length)];
}
Image.asset(listImagesnotFound.toString()),
```

Comment: You have put wrong variable to Image.asset, change to Image.asset(imageToShow.toString()),

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 dynamic listImagesnotFound = [
    "assets/cactusno.jpg",
    "assets/colorednot.jpg",
    "assets/juno.jpg",
    "assets/notfound.png",
    "assets/robno.png",
    "assets/spano.jpg"
  ];
Random rnd;

Widget buildImage(BuildContext context) {
  int min = 0;
  int max = listImagesnotFound.length-1;
  rnd = new Random();
  int r = min + rnd.nextInt(max - min);
  String image_name  = listImagesnotFound[r].toString();
  return Image.asset(image_name);
}

Or

Image img() {
  int min = 0;
  int max = listImagesnotFound.length-1;
  rnd = new Random();
  int r = min + rnd.nextInt(max - min);
  String image_name  = listImagesnotFound[r].toString();
  return Image.asset(image_name);
}

Then call your buildImage or img function like :

buildImage(context), 

or

img(),
```

Random number can gererate any number so if you are not using min or max value it will return you an error if random number generated is larger then your assets list index.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code to,

```
Image.asset(imageToShow.toString()),
```